# WWW::Selenium 'cant find element'

Tags: perl, selenium

I'm having trouble with WWW::Selenium finding an href.

Here is the HTML element I'm looking for.

```
<a href="/auctions?organization_id=2">Sell Products</a>
```

Here is the Perl code I'm using.

```
$sel->click('//a[contains(@href, "/auctions?organization_id=2")]');
```

Here is the error that WWW::Selenium is outputting.

```
Error requesting http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/:
ERROR: Element //a[contains(@href, "/auctions?organization_id=2")] not found
```

Any tips/help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT
Adding the surrounding HTML to aid in the troubleshooting.

```
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="/auctions?organization_id=2">Sell Products</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
        <a href="/dashboard?_tab=seller">Seller Dashboard</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not sure, but you may have to escape the `\?`, also, you can try just with `organization_id=2` and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, I tried both: escaping the ? and just organization_id=2, same issue.

Comment: Would it be possible to simply use the xPath?

Comment: Ok, I'm using an xpath locator from firefox, it says that link has an xpath of **`id('menu-main-menu')/x:li[3]/x:a`** I will modify the code and post the results.

Comment: The xpath **`id('menu-main-menu')/x:li[3]/x:a`** caused the same error.

Comment: Haven't tested but escaping the ? should do the trick... Have you tried using &#63; instead of ? making the string to "/auctions&#63;organization_id=2"

Comment: `ERROR: Element //a[contains(@href, "/auctions&#63;organization_id=2")] not found` I got the same error.

Comment: Other common problems... Does the page contain iframes? Is the element in question visible/active at the time of the search? If there are scripts populating page content, have they finished?

Comment: Thank you @rutter. I added Perl code `sleep 5;` before the element causing the issue and the issue is resolved. The page wasn't loaded by the time the test executed which cased the error **not found**.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using hard-coded `sleep` I would suggest using `wait_for_element_present`.

```
my $locator = q{//a[contains(@href, "/auctions?organization_id=2")]};
$sel->wait_for_element_present($locator, $timeout)
$sel->click($locator);
```